# Spring Batch:- One reader multiple writers

Tags: spring-batch

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MRkL.jpg) I have a flat file which has two types of data. such as I have a Comma delimited file that has information of a students. There are multiple files like class A students, class B students etc.

Data in file is like first line has the class information and the rest has student information. So I want to put the class information to class table and student information to student table.

First line would always be of HeaderDataDAO type and all other would be of StudentDataDAO.

How can I achieve this?

My File structure 
Class-A*10*2013-14
1*Stone*Barrett*1964-10-19
2*Armando*Stone*1973-02-04****
3*Armando*Logan*1986-12-25
4*Latifah*Barnett*1959-07-24
5*Cassandra*Moses*1956-09-14*********
6*Audra*Hopkins*1984-08-30
7*Upton*Morrow*1973-02-04
8*Melodie*Velasquez*1953-04-26
9*Sybill*Nolan*1951-06-24*****
10*Glenna*Little*1953-08-27

StudentDataDAO.java

public class StudentDataDAO {

```
private long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Date birthDate;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Date getBirthDate() {
    return birthDate;
}

public void setBirthDate(String birthDate) throws ParseException {
    if (!birthDate.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        SimpleDateFormat spf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        this.birthDate = spf.parse(birthDate);
    } else {
        this.birthDate = null;
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "CustomerData [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", birthDate=" + birthDate
            + "]";
}
```

}

HeaderDataDAO.java

public class HeaderDataDAO {

```
private String className;
private String numberOfStudent;
private String batch;

public String getClassName() {
    return className;
}

public void setClassName(String className) {
    this.className = className;
}

public String getNumberOfStudent() {
    return numberOfStudent;
}

public void setNumberOfStudent(String numberOfStudent) {
    this.numberOfStudent = numberOfStudent;
}

public String getBatch() {
    return batch;
}

public void setBatch(String batch) {
    this.batch = batch;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "HeaderData [className=" + className + ", numberOfStudent=" + numberOfStudent + ", batch=" + batch + "]";
}
```

}

Comment: Your question is about a standard SB job and net is full of example about CSV with header + detail and different  writer for different type.
Please try yourself first and only after ask to SO.

Comment: Sir my question is not about standard SB job i guess i have created a confusion by saying header but let me clarify it . By header i mean details of the file like now I have attached an image in my post from which you can see my header contains data as Class-A*10*2013-14 these are different entities and the other data is of different entities. so how to read this type of file and store it in db is my  question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CompositeItemWriter` below is sample config

```
 <bean id="compositeWriter"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter">
        <property name="delegates">
            <list>      
                <ref bean="classWriter" />
                <ref bean="studentWriter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: I have the information of the class and the student in a single file how would i distinguish one another?

Comment: in which object you are reading data ? could you please share that  object structure

Comment: I have added my two different DAO and the file structure to my post

Answer (score 0):

Using [CompositeItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemWriter.html). Find sample over here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/compositeItemWriterSampleJob.xml 
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-samples/1.0.1.RELEASE/jobs/compositeItemWriterSampleJob.xml

Comment: the example you provide I have looked into it but its single type of DAO i need to different DAO because i have single file contains two types of data ie student data and class data. so I created two DAO one ClassDAO and one StudentDAO.